# convert 56 kbps to monthly usage in GB

Tags: math

From my internet connection (SIM card) of 56kbps (unlimited data) what would be total gigabytes of data I can consume provided I was using it continuously?

My basic math:
30 days = 2592000 seconds
56 * 2592000 = 145152000 kb  = 141750 MB = 141 GB

Does this calculation make sense?

Comment: I think you're missing a factor 1/8 there because kbps is kilo**bit** per second and you're converting it to giga**bytes**. Should be 17.3 GB by my count

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic maths is good, unfortunately you were tricked by the notations which are unfortunately very confusing in this domain.

1) Lower case b stands for a bit, while capital B is a byte, which is made of 8 bits. So when you get 56 kb/s you actually get 56/8 = 7 kB/s.

This gives you 1814400 kB per month.

2) Now comes the second problem. The definition of what is a kB, a MB or a GB is not uniform. Normally you would expect that there are defined following powers of ten (as in any other science) in which case your 1814400 kB per month would convert into 18144 MB per month or 18.1 GB per month.

However for historical reason MB are sometimes defined as 1024 kB and GB as 1024 MB. In this case you would get 17719 MB per month or 17.3 GB per month.

Which convention you should use depend what you actually want to do with it. But such a small difference is probably irrelevant to you compared to potential fluctuations in the actual transfer rate of your connection.

Comment: The 1024 factor comes from the power of 2 which is closest to 1000. That is what I always used. Recently I have noted that some places utilize a different notation for multiples of 1000 and of 1024. I have seen kB (kilobyte) meaning 1000 bytes and kiB (kibibyte) meaning 1024 bytes, as well as extensions to higher powers. I don't like it but some do (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte).